# Secure Boot & admin password

Tags: arch-linux, uefi, bios, secure-boot

I have a PC with a mechanical interrupt in order to enable different hdds and use different OS.
Windows has bee installed with bios legacy.  
 
I want to install in the other HDD archlinux.
When I try to disable secure boot, the enter is greyed out. I followed the instruction and I set the admin password, still greyed out. I have an ASUS b150m-c motherboard.

Comment: I would suggest that you post your answer as a solution rather than editing the question.

Comment: I rolled back your recent edit tagging the title with "CLOSED". If one of the answers solves your issue, consider accepting it. If you have a solution different from all answers, consider adding that solution as a separate answer and accept it later. Accepting an answer will mark the question as resolved. Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE
Now works,I think it was a combination of bad fstab and
"boot from Storage Device - UEFI driver first" not set in the UEFI/BIOS settings

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using legacy BIOS boot, it probably means Secure Boot is either already disabled or overridden by the selection of a legacy BIOS boot method.

Secure Boot is UEFI-only technology: it cannot be applied to operating systems that are using legacy BIOS boot.

Comment: ok,, can I install arch-linux "UEFI-version" on the other HDD? 
because I have installed it but does not work (does not boot, start the uefi instead), I thought it was for secure boot option but I not sure anymore

Comment: It depends on your BIOS settings: if configured for "legacy boot **only**", then an UEFI version of Arch won't work without changing the settings. Also, an UEFI bootloader usually cannot start an OS that uses the legacy BIOS boot method, and a legacy BIOS bootloader *definitely* cannot start an OS that uses UEFI, so if you want a boot menu of OSs, you'll need to use the same boot method for all of them. But if you use a mechanical switch to select your system disk, then that's not a problem for you.

Comment: Unfortunately Asus's manuals for your motherboard won't show all the BIOS settings on the "Boot menu" page, so I cannot give you exact suggestions. Any sub-menus of, and any menu items after the "CSM (Compatibility Support Module)" would be important here.

Comment: ok
* Launch CSM - enabled
* boot device control -  UEFI and legacy OPROM
* boot from network device - Ignore
* boot from Storage Device - Legacy only ( possibilities Ignore, Legacy only, UEFI driver first)
* boot from PCI-E/PCI Expansion Devices - Legacy only ( possibilities Ignore, Legacy only, UEFI driver first).
** I thought "boot from Storage Device - UEFI driver first) could be the right setting but I was afraid to mess up windows boot

Comment: You are entirely correct: "boot from storage device - UEFI driver first" means that the system first looks for UEFI-bootable disks, and if none of those are available, then legacy BIOS-bootable disks. That would allow you to use both UEFI- and BIOS-bootable disks, as long as only one type of bootable disk is visible to the system at any time. As I understand, it would suit your purposes, and should not harm your Windows boot at all. And it is simple to change back if necessary.

Comment: Note that if you ever have to install an operating system that would have to be legacy BIOS-bootable, and its installation media supports both boot methods, you may have to change the setting back to "boot from storage device - Legacy only" for the duration of the installation, to ensure the installation will happen in legacy BIOS-bootable mode as intended. Most dual-mode OS installers will detect the boot mode that was used to boot the installer, and install the OS to use the same mode.

Comment: Hi, thanks.
It was probably a combination of wrong settings for grub and bad UEFI settings